# Why my JavaScript file can't access defined constant from another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoin-testnet

I'm going to embed data into the blockchain with OP_RETURN (testnet).

I have two files in one directory.
The first one `keys.js` contains code that generates address and private key for bitcoin testnet transactions.

keys.js:

```js
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
const { testnet } = bitcoin.networks
const myKeyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: testnet });
//extract the publickey
const publicKey = myKeyPair.publicKey;
//get the private key
const myWIF = myKeyPair.toWIF();
//get an address from the myKeyPair we generated above.
const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({
  pubkey: publicKey,
  network: testnet
});

console.log("myAdress: " + address + " \nmyWIF: " + myWIF);
```

The second one `op_return.js` contains method that allows me to embed random text into blockchain.

This is the end of op_return.js:

```js
const importantMessage = 'RANDOM TEXT INTO BLOCKCHAIN'
buildOpReturnTransaction(myKeyPair, importantMessage)
.then(pushTransaction)
.then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

The problem is with constant `myKeyPair` in `op_return.js` because after typing `node op_return` in node.js command prompt error comes out:

```
buildOpReturnTransaction(myKeyPair, importantMessage)
                         ^

ReferenceError: myKeyPair is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\mydir\op_return:71:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Comment: what is your question? you don't define `myKeyPair`

Comment: @zb22 I defined it in the first file ```const myKeyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: testnet });```.

Comment: but you don't have access to it in `op_return.js`

Comment: op_return.js is trying to reference a variable defined in keys.js. Have you tried exporting `myKeypPair` from keys.js?

Comment: @terrymorse How can I do it? I tried with global variable but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll explain export and import in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared in one JavaScript file is not automatically accessible in a different file, but there is a feature available in Node.js that lets you import and export variables via [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Say you have defined the variable `myKeyPair` in 'file1.js', but you want to use `myKeyPair` in 'file2.js'.

The solution is to export `myKeyPair` in file1.js:

```js
// file1.js

const myKeyPair = ['hello', 'world'];

module.exports.myKeyPair = myKeyPair;
```

Then, to use `myKeyPair` in file2.js, you import it from file1.js with a `require()` statement.

```js
// file2.js

const myKeyPair = require('./file1.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `myKeyPair` in `keys.js` and not in `op_return.js`. If you need to define it in one file and use it in another, you need to define the variable as a global. Checkout the link below for global variables in node

`https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/`

Comment: I have already set is as global (```global.myKeyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: testnet });``` and the same error occurs